# How can i get 'pk' or 'id' in get_context_data from ListView

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

How can i get 'pk' or 'id'  in get_context_data from ListView

```
class AllListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'all_products'
    queryset = Product.objects.all
    template_name = 'jewelry_store/home.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super(AllListView,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['collections'] =  Collection.objects.all
        context['products'] = self.queryset
        context['cool'] = Collection.objects.filter(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk'))
```

in output it gives empty  queryset
[image]

in urls

```
path('', views.AllListView.as_view(), name='all_products')
``
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your path has no `pk` URL parameter, so `self.kwargs.get('pk')` will be `None`, and thus not match an item.

You should encode the primary key in the URL, like:

```
path('<int:pk>/', views.AllListView.as_view(), name='all_products')
```

and in the `ListView`, you can then indeed retrieve the corresponding `Collection`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class AllListView(ListView):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    template_name = 'jewelry_store/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['collections'] =  Collection.objects.all()
        context['cool'] = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=self.kwargs['pk'])
        return context
```

Comment: still the same , erro: r context['cool'] = get_object_or_404(Collection, pk=self.kwargs['pk']) #id=1
KeyError: 'pk'

Comment: @hebel.dev: you should edit the path to use an `<int:pk>/` parameter, and thus visit the page with `42/` where `42` is the primary key of an *existing* `Collection` record.